# diff two directories for changes and format output to use for script

Tags: bash, scripting, diff

I currently try to monitor two directories and subdirectories for changes in files. The directories contain the same set of files, some of them are changed. So I thought I might use the `diff` command to create a list of changed files with the line numbers and changes. I need this list to further process it by another script.

Since you can use the `diff -r` option to recursively check for changes, I tried to format the output to suit my needs. I can't use the default multiline output, but want to have the following:

`file_1`:

```
my first line
my second line
my third line
```

`file_2`:

```
my first line
my changed second line
my third line
```

My desired output would either look like:

```
file_2:2:my changed second line
```

or (if that is easier):

```
file_1:2:my second line
file_2:2:my changed second line
```

I managed to produce the output without the filename with the following parameters:

```
diff -qbBwr --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format=":%d:%L" --new-line-format=":%dn:%L"  file_1 file_2
```

which results in

```
:2:my second line
:2:my changed second line
```

But there are two problems:

- The lfmt option does not work with the recursive option `-r`
- I do not get the filename

So finally the question is:

Does anybody know how to `diff` two directories in a way that I get the desired output from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this ought to do what you need:

```
diff -r -U0 a/ b/ | awk '/^+++ / {filename=$2; next} /^@@ / {split($3,a,","); line=substr(a[1],2)} /^+/ {text=substr($0,2); print filename ":" line ":" text; line++}'
```

Basically, it does an ordinary recursive diff, and then discards the bit you don't want. awk is cool for stuff like this.

`diff -U0` gives output like this:

```
--- a   2014-07-01 17:05:46.257447351 +0100
+++ b   2014-07-01 17:05:56.157524562 +0100
@@ -2 +2 @@
-my second line
+my changed second line
```

The awk script takes the filename from the `+++` line, the line number from the `@@` line, and the text from the `+` line, and then prints them with the colons you wanted:

```
file_2:2:my changed second line
```

EDIT: I noticed a script error if two lines together were edited. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much for that script and the explanation, i already thought about using awk or similar, just am not too good at it. I am wondering on thing though: What version of awk are you using, sind the script produces no output for me (i am using GNU Awk 4.0.1)

Comment: I have GNU Awk 4.1.1

Comment: Perhaps the diff produced nothing?

Comment: the problem was that my shell (bash) needs quoting of the + signs in your script, otherwise it fails to match correctly.